# Library Suggestion: International phone number drop down with country codes, flags and a search bar option

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap

In my angular project I have used the [international-phone-number library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-international-phone-number). It has got country codes, flags and the dropdown can be navigated by typing the name of the country, which is okay, but I would like a more user-friendly dropdown that has a search bar where I can enter the country name, in addition to the other features.

Would be helpful if anyone can suggest such a library.